# Mac terminal error -bash: command not found - El Capitan 10.11.13

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, postgis

I'm getting an error message when I first open my Mac terminal -

```
-bash: Applications: command not found
```

Oddly (or maybe not so oddly), when I open another tab, I sometimes get a different error -

```
-bash: README.md: command not found
```

or

```
-bash: [: missing `]'
```

I just noticed that this morning... there are two things that I did last night that I feel may have led to this, but I'm not sure if I am correct, nor do I know how to appropriately fix this issue.  My OS is El Capitan 10.11.13.

First off, last night, I used Homebrew to install PostGIS 2.2 - my Postgres version is 9.5.1.

Second, I made a Github pull request for one of my projects (I'm not sure how a pull request could upset my bash profile, but Github's standard readme format is README.md, so I thought I'd better mention this here).

My bash profile seems clean to me -

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin
*    #EDITED TO INCLUDE THIS ASTERISK, WHICH I NEGLECTED BEFORE
```

Can anyone shed some light on what happened and how I can go about fixing this?  I'm fairly new to using the terminal, so I'm not quite sure how to interpret this.

Comment: Add `set -x` to the start of your profile, and see what it does — be prepared to be horrified.  But it will likely tell you what's going wrong.  If not, add `set -x` to a few more places.

Comment: Thanks - Of course I don't know how to interpret most of the output, but these two lines do appear toward the end: + Applications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public log.txt bash: Applications: command not found. Your thoughts?

Comment: That looks like you have a line starting with `*` in your profile.  The shell expands that `*` into the (files and) directories in your home directory.  Probably replace the `*` with a `#` — but you need to analyze the line of the script to decide what is best.

Comment: Ok that's interesting - yes, I actually had a solitary `*` in my bash_profile underneath the last line - I didn't think to include it in my question because I didn't know it had a function.  I just commented it out and now my terminal opens just fine.  Will commenting out this `*` have any deleterious effects?

Comment: Commenting it out means it takes an immeasurably small amount longer to process the profile.  Deleting it avoids confusion and saves (immeasurably) on the time taken to start up.  Leaving it as a comment (making into a comment) does no harm at all and does do you some good (avoids noise when starting up).

Comment: Great!  Thank you all very much for your help.  This solved my problem and was very insightful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to troubleshoot Bash startup problems**:

To build on [Jonathan Leffler's helpful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35927558/45375#comment-59513735):

- From an existing terminal window, run `script log.txt bash -lxv`

  - This will create a new login (`-l`) shell (which is the type of shell `Terminal.app` on OSX creates by default) and log all its startup activities.
  - In addition to capturing regular output,

    - `-v` shows *unexpanded source* lines as they're being read.
    - `-x` shows the *expanded, individual* commands that are executed, prefixed with `+`.
- Execute `exit` to terminate that shell, which will save everything that was just printed to `log.txt`.
- Study file `log.txt` to see what's going on.

---

**What turned out to be the OP's problem:**

- A stray `*` on a single line in their profile expanded to an alphabetically sorted list of the names of the files and folders in the then-current directory (a process called pathname expansion or globbing).

  - Not only is a `*` as its own command (or the start of a command) not *useful*, it could result in *unwanted execution of a command* (see below).
- Bash then tried to execute the result of this expansion as a *command to execute*, with the 1st word (whitespace-separated token) interpreted as the command *name*.

  - This failed, because that first word *happened not be* a command name.
  - However, if the first word happened to be a valid command name such as `file`, *that command would execute*.
    (Unless the current dir. happens to be in the `$PATH`, it doesn't matter whether the first matching filename is an executable file or not - all that matters is whether the name matches an existing command name).
- On startup, the user's home dir. was the working dir.; by contrast, opening another tab later uses the then-current working dir., whatever it happens to be.

  - This explains the differing symptoms, as globbing in different directories will typically result in different name lists, the respective first word of which Bash will try to execute.

Comment: Thank you - Of course I don't know how to interpret most of the output, but these two lines do appear toward the end: `+ Applications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public log.txt
bash: Applications: command not found`.  Your thoughts?

Comment: It means that during startup something outputs the string "Applications Desktop Documents Downloads Library Movies Music Pictures Public log.txt" (whether directly or as a result of an expansion - probably globbing, as Jonathan suggests), which is then interpreted as a _command_ to execute, resulting in the error; add `-v` to the command to see the _source_ line of that command.

Comment: Thanks buddy, this was really helpful!

Comment: @skwidbreth: Glad to hear it; I've updated my answer to explain your specific symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone's help here, I was able to resolve this issue.  When I posted my question, I left a tiny but important detail out of my bash profile - a lone asterisk on the last line.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin  #ADDS MYSQL TO PATH EVERY TIME TERMINAL OPENS
*
```

I didn't even notice this thing before, let alone understand that it was doing anything.  I commented it out and now everything runs perfectly.  I'm not sure if this asterisk is a standard part of the bash profile or not, but if it has been there all along, it didn't cause me any trouble until this morning, after I had installed PostGIS and made a Github pull request.  I'm not sure why those actions would have triggered this problem, but I'm trying to be as descriptive as possible in case anyone else runs into this.