# .bash_profile loading but source not working

Tags: bash, macos, unix, virtualenvwrapper

I've installed `virtualenvwrapper` in OS X and am trying to edit my `.bash_profile` so I don't have to `source` it everytime I open a terminal. After editing each time I open the terminal I get the following error:

```
: not founds: /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh.
```

Here is my `.bash_profile`, and I know it is getting loaded:

```
alias e='emacs -nw'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Also worth noting that if I run `source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh` manually in the terminal it works.

Comment: Do you have `/usr/local/bin` included in your `$PATH`?

Comment: The error message you're seeing is _not_ what Bash reports when you try to `source` a non-existent file, so the question is: who's reporting this error message? I suggest you trace Bash's startup activities as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35927780/45375) of mine.

Comment: The error message also looks like something has DOS line endings.